# Connect MS OneDrive from Window Service (background task)

Tags: onedrive

I went thru at Microsoft OneDrive API tutorials and they are only guiding people how to connect OneDrive with UI mode. Which means there will be a prompt asking user to authenticate access to the OneDrive (OAuth2). What if I want this to be skipped, or the other way meaning, I want everything authenticate in silent mode (service mode)? Any guidance?

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access OneDrive in the context of a user, you need to use the interactive OAuth2 flow to be granted consent and receive an access_token and refresh_token. This is only required when initially setting up the configuration.

Once you have a refresh_token available, that can be silently redeemed for a new access_token.

If you want to make a background task / Windows Service that stays connected to OneDrive in the context of a user, you would need to have an interactive configuration experience to "Add a OneDrive Account" and go through the OAuth2 flow. Once that has been completed, the service can use the stored refresh_token to generate new access_tokens and make API calls.

There are a few scenarios where the refresh_token will become invalid, that you would need to prompt for credentials again:

- The user changes their password
- The user revokes access to the application
- An enterprise configures an expiration period on refresh_tokens (OneDrive for Business only)

Your service would need to handle these scenarios and have a way to prompt that additional configuration was required.

Comment: is any alternative way instead of this?

Comment: OneDrive for Business (not Personal) has an option to use OAuth2 Password flow. There are more details about that here: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/